# Convergence of Monotone Sequence in Affine-Extended Reals

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

For a monotonically increasing sequence $(x_n)$ in $\mathbb{R}$, we have that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} x_n$ exists and is finite iff $(x_n)$ is bounded, i.e. $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} x_n = \sup (x_n)$.

Let $\overline{\mathbb{R}} = \mathbb{R} \cup \{\infty,-\infty\}$ with topology generated by intervals of the form $(a,b), (a,\infty],[-\infty,a)$. Can we extend the previous theorem to state that any monotonically increasing sequence converges to a supremum (which we allow to be infinite)?

Comment: I do not agree; any monotone sequence of real numbers has always limit. The limit is finite iff the sequence is bounded. You should change your statement in "for a monotonically increasing sequence $(x_n)\in\mathbb R$, we have that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}x_n$ exists and it is FINITE iff $(x_n)$ is bounded

Answer (score 3):

In $\overline{\mathbb R}$, it is indeed the case that every monotonically increasing sequence converges to its supremum.

Incidentally, I disagree with Avitus's comment.  When I say that  a sequence of real numbers has a limit, I mean that it has a real number as its limit, unless I have given a clear indication that $\infty$ is allowed.  A clear indication might be saying "has a (possibly infinite) limit" or saying something about working in $\overline{\mathbb R}$ rather than $\mathbb R$.